# JavaScript threads implementation in Spidermonkey

Tags: javascript, multithreading, actor, spidermonkey

I need to implement multithreading like Web Workers inside my app, in which we planning to use Spidermonkey to execute javascript. I want something like that API:

```
function BackgroundWorker() {
    // do something
}

someglobalobject.spawnWorker(BackgroundWorker);
```

where someglobalobject.spawnWorker is a C binding that spawns thread (or not if worker is deferred), creates new JSContext, transfers function *BackgroundWorker* to that context and executes it.
We planning to implement resource sharing through message passing to/from worker (worker can register some event hooks or receive messages by C binding call), and also maybe through C binding to some sort of shared memory (STM perhaps). At best we want to implement some kind of Erlang-style actors for JS. So I have a few questions about it:

1. Is there some examples how this thing can be implemented (but not too complex like Web Workers)?
2. What is the footprint of JSContext? It is possible create a lot of them, or it can cause some performance bottlenecks?
3. Is there an ability to pause JavaScript execution inside some C binding that called from that JavaScript?